# woocommerce scheduled subscription payment firing twice

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

There is an issue on my WordPress site where the woocommerce_scheduled_subscription_payment action is firing twice causing stripe to double charge customers on subscription renewal orders. Does anyone have a solution?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaWGL.png)

Comment: Suggest that you reach out to WooCommerce support to get some help with this.

Comment: Did you find any helps on this one @Adam? WooCommerce support refused to help us because we are using custom code :/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Adam. The file you talked about is from your theme right? We don't have any files with that name.

Comment: Hi, yes it is a file in our theme. are you calling WC_Gateway_Stripe anywhere in your theme code files? if so you can make the update to call it as $stripe = woocommerce_gateway_stripe()->get_main_stripe_gateway();